# Enumerating an array of exactly 2 (slightly different) objects in OpenAPI 3.1.0?

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi

I need to document a REST endpoint that takes the following request body:

```
{
  "variables": [
    {
      "name": "groupGuid",
      "value": "...",
      "typeConstraint": "string",
    },
    {
      "name": "addMembership",
      "value": "...",
      "typeConstraint": "boolean",
    }
  ]
}
```

The `variables` array **must take exactly 2** objects:

- one with the required `name` `groupGuid` and `typeConstraint` `string`,
- and the other with the required `name` `addMembership` and `typeConstraint` `boolean`.

The type of their respective `value`s are specified by `typeConstraint`, but the actual values of the `value` properties are otherwise unconstrained.

Currently, I've got this, which is very underspecified (and possibly wrong) and relies on notes I've manually included:

```
  '/test':
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                variables:
                  type: array
                  uniqueItems: true
                  description: 'Must contain exactly 2 objects, with the following `name`s: (1) `groupGuid`: GUID of the group, (2) `addMembership`: Whether the task will add (true) or remove (false) members from the group.'
                  items:
                    type: object
                    additionalProperties: false
                    properties:
                      name:
                        enum:
                          - groupGuid
                          - addMembership
                        type: string
                      value:
                        type:
                          - string
                          - boolean
                      typeConstraint:
                        type: string
                        enum:
                          - string
                          - boolean
                        description: The type of `value`.
```

Is it possible to properly spec these requirements in YAML / OpenAPI 3.1.0, and if so, how? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to show both objects in the example body and accept either or both of them, perhaps you could use [anyOf](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/).

Below an example

```
paths:
  /test:
    post:
      tags:
        - Test
      description: "Must contain exactly 2 objects, with the following `name`s: (1) `groupGuid`: GUID of the group, (2) `addMembership`: Whether the task will add (true) or remove (false) members from the group."
      requestBody:
          required: true
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                properties:
                  variables:                    
                    type: array
                    uniqueItems: true
                    items:
                      anyOf:
                        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Object1'
                        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Object2'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Sucess

components:     
  schemas: 
    Object1:
      type: object
      description: "The value here is string"
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        value:
          type: string
        typeConstraint:
          type: string
    Object2:
      type: object
      description: "The value here is boolean"
      properties:
        name:
          type: string          
        value:
          type: string
        typeConstraint:
          type: boolean
```

Comment: Thanks, however what I need is more like "exactlyOf". Not either or both - precisely both are required (and nothing additional). I'm not sure it's possible.